# What would trigger a Windows 10 PC to do a full factory reload automatically?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore, reinstall, wipe

I got called out on a support call today where the computer had completely reloaded Windows 10 from scratch. All existing customer data, configuration, apps, etc were gone.  There wasn't even anything in the Windows.old folder.

It appears to have happened last night around 4-6 pm, and the manager tells me nobody was using the computer since last week.

When powering it up, it went through the Welcome To Windows screens and required a user to be created.

I am not aware of any way to trigger a complete system wipe and reinstall without user interaction, so I am pretty sure this had to be user-initiated.

Testing the hard drive indicates a good drive - no errros/bad sectors.

Is there anything that comes to mind that could trigger this, or should we assume someone was using the PC without authorization and triggered the wipe to cover their tracks?

Thanks for any insight.

UPDATE: I have conducted some tests on a VM and I can confirm: it *is* possible to initiate a full system restore and deletion of all user data from within Windows (no need to reboot into EFI or Windows Boot).  The process is as follows:

1. Open Settings (gear) app and search for Recovery Options.
2. In Recovery, click the Get Started button below "Reset This PC"
3. Choose the option "Remove everything" (screenshot below)
4. Choose the Local option for the source of Windows installation media.
5. Answer any remaining questions
6. The computer will reboot and initiate full system restore and wipe out the user files, and will not require further input from the user to confirm this operation.
   [image]

This confirms that it's entirely possible to initiate a full System Restore with erasure of user data directly from the Windows environment without going through a reboot process or shell.  Therefore remote users and also applications could initiate this process with no need for a local user to be present. (Thanks @starcat for your input also)

This opens up another set of possible sources for this reset: it could have been an app that initiated the reset, or it could have been a remote user.  It seems the most likely scenario would be the new Malwarebytes software, since the reset happened very shortly after installing MB.  But MB support assured me their software has no ability to perform this type of action.  I suppose it could have been dormant malware, which was triggered to run a system restore upon detection of the new MB software, but that doesn't seem likely as we were already running another version of the paid Malwarebytes product on this PC before upgrading to MB EDR.

TLDR: I'm still stumped, but there are a lot more possibilities to initiate such a system restore than I originally thought.

Comment: There would have to be a significant hardware event (bad disk ) for we Windows to try its own repair but you say the disk is good so likely user initiated in this case

Comment: There would be nothing that would happen automatically that would cause a Reset to happen. Sounds like Windows was reinstalled outside of Windows which is the **only** way I know to avoid Windows.old from being generated

Comment: To clarify, windows.old exists, but it is an empty folder.

Comment: I ran an extended test on the disk with WD tools, but it came back clean.

Comment: Was the machine managed as part of a corporate network and might it have been wiped remotely, either accidentally or on purpose?

Comment: No, it is only a small workgroup LAN of about 15 computers, no AD or domain.  I am the only IT admin for this site.  FYI I had just installed Malwarebytes EDR on all systems at this location. No other issues at the site.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a complete system restore (deleting all user data) remotely? wouldn't that require a user to be in front of the computer to manually press buttons after rebooting into EFI/windows boot screen to select System Restore? or is it possible to fully initiate and approve this from Windows before the reboot happens?

Comment: It is possible to completely reinstall a machine and delete all user data remotely. For example [Microsoft Intune](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/remote-actions/devices-wipe) has that ability. The machine would have to be enrolled in Intune for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be concerned the hard drive could have been switched and that is the reason for the reinstall. Customer data could be stolen rather than lost. If the machine has tamper switches, it would be a good thing to check.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The system did a reload from the recovery partition so it seems unlikely the drive was switched due to theft

Comment: @John: The whole disk could have been cloned and then the new disk was reset.

Comment: @John the system won't use the recovery partition without human intervention, so it is not as unlikely as you think. You need to go in advanced options from the repair screen to get the reset options.

Comment: That is what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @John yes, so since there was a very high possibility of human intervention and the drive is wiped, the computer should be examined to see if it was tampered with.

Comment: I don't think the drive was switched, as I ran R-Studio and can see a few deleted files still there.  But it does appear all user files were deleted by the System Restore. Yes my main concern is that I can't think of a way to initiate a System Restore *without* user intervention - this points to a user either accidentally or intentionally initiating the restore.

Comment: @RyanGriggs it is like John said, the drive could have been cloned before reset.  If something went wrong in the cloning process, some files could be left over but it could have been missing something for the computer to start... which would explain the reason for a reset. Even if the hard drive was not switched, the main concern remains the customers data anyway, as to if it was just lost or was it stolen.